# Amazon s3 boto3: Check if upload is done

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm having a user upload a file to s3 storage directly. My issue is that while that file is uploading, I want to run a worker to check if the upload is done, and if it is, do some processing.

If a file upload is in progress, is there a way I can find it from boto3 separately using it's key and bucket? If I can find it, can I check if the upload is done?

Comment: Did you check S3 event triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [S3Transfers](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#ref-s3transfer-usage)
It takes callBack parameter which gives you upload/download percentage.

Comment: what about an empty file?